# Why memory access violation is happening?

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a string,
No idea why am I getting this below error as `Unhandled exception at 0x00f818c2 in CPP_TEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00f87838.`?
Please help me.

```
void swap(char* in, int start, int end)
{
    char *temp = new char;
    *temp = in[start];
    in[start] = in[end];//Unhandled exception at 0x00f818c2 in CPP_TEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00f87838.
    in[end] = *temp;
}
void Reverse(char* in, int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end)
    {
        cout << in <<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(start != end)
        {
            swap(in, start++, end--);
            //Reverse(in, start, end);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{


    char* in = "Hello";
    Reverse(in, 0, 4);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `in` points to a string literal. You cannot modify it. Plus, you have a memory leak in `swap`.

Comment: Normally, one would use at least `std::swap`, if not `std::reverse`. Neither have these bugs. Anyway, a `char *` pointing to a string literal is deprecated in C++ (you should get a compiler warning, so turn them on/up if you don't) and illegal in C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string literal is not modifiable, and yet you are attempting to modify it. Use a modifiable string:

```
char in[] = "Hello";
```

---

In `swap`, you leak memory. You don't need to dynamically allocate memory there. The code can be

```
void swap(char* in, int start, int end)
{
    char temp = in[start];
    in[start] = in[end];
    in[end] = temp;
}
```

---

```
while(start != end)
{
    swap(in, start++, end--);
    //Reverse(in, start, end);
}
```

If `end - start` is an odd number, this loop will never terminate.